# How long to hold a JDBC Connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In our application we have separate connection pools configured for each module. One module requires use of some `PreparedStatement` to be reused often. For this need, I would like to hold the connection forever, so that I need not create new `PreparedStatement`. Is it safe to hold the Connection like this?

Comment: Just close it as soon as you are done with it, everything else is an unnecessary complication of your code, unless you have proven that it is a real performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider the usage of a connection pool implementation -- like UCP(Oracle), bonecp, dbcp, cp030, etc. This pool pool will maintain the connection management, and you don't have to worry.

Comment: cp030 is being used. I don't want to close the connection after a PreparedStatement is executed. In this way I can retain & reuse the PreparedStatement

Comment: So, the connection is reused all the time -- if you are using spring then a connection borrow/return will be taken care by the framework. or if you are directly coding to borrow the connection you must return the same to the pool, so your connection is retained.

Answer (score 0):

Connection pools typically keep connection objects for a very long time (could be months). There is nothing wrong in that.